# Using software to apply tests under different perspectives (sets of hypotheses $(H_0, H_1)$)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, assumptions, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I have read very useful [paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2857732) "Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney or t-test? On assumptions for hypothesis tests and multiple interpretations of decision rules" by Fay and Proschan (2010).

This paper helped me to understand how hypothesis tests work in different statistical packages (R, scipy.stats, etc.). But I still have a couple of questions about their usage, because I don't have much experience with them.

Below there is a table from this paper which shows that (in the context of 2-sample location tests) some fixed decision rule (column) can be used under different perspectives (rows) and some fixed perspective (row) can be tested using different decision rules (columns):

[image: 2-sample tests]

Given this table I got the following interpretation of how we can use statistical software (for example functions [scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu.html) and [scipy.stats.ttest_ind](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_ind.html)) to perform hypothesis tests under different perspectives at once. Usually this topic is not well documented in the software documentation (and manuals often describe just one most popular perspective for a given test).

Firstly, the choice of function sets the decision rule but it doesn't set the perspective. For example, it is clear that `scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu` function fixes the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney decision rule, which is denoted as WMW in the table (*and $\delta_W$ in other parts of the paper; below we will work with this function and its decision rule, but for other functions / decision rules the procedure is analogous*). In other words, it fixes the first column in the table. This leads to fixation of the formula for the test statistic and its null distribution (let's assume for simplicity that we always call the function with the parameters `alternative=two-sided` and `method='exact'`). Hence, this results in a fixation of the formula for the p-value: $\text{p-value}_W(\mathbf{x}^{(n)}, \mathbf{y}^{(m)}) = \inf\big\{\alpha \in (0,1): \, \delta_W(\mathbf{x}^{(n)}, \mathbf{y}^{(m)}, \alpha) = 1 \big\}$.
It is important to note that this doesn't lead to the fixation of some perspective $\{H_0,H_1,\mathrm{P}\}$, since the alternative hypothesis $H_1$ and the full set of the allowed distributions $\mathrm{P} = H_0 \sqcup H_1$ are not fixed. However, this implies the requirement that the null hypothesis $H_0$ should be chosen in a such a way that the null distribution of the test statistic should be the one that is assumed by the decision rule. In the case of `scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu` this means that the null should be $H_0 = \{(F,G) \in \mathrm{P}: F = G\}$ (due to exchangeability property of the WMW decision rule; all valid perspectives for the WMW, listed in the first column of the table, have this property; note that $H_0$ is not fully defined here since $\mathrm{P}$ is not fixed).

Let's assume that some user called function `scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu` on some samples $\mathbf{x}^{(n)}$ and $\mathbf{y}^{(m)}$ and told us the resulting p-value. Then, as I understood, we can make inferences for any of the valid and consistent (yy) perspectives for WMW decision rule, listed in the aforementioned table. Each such perspective (triplet $\{H_0,H_1,\mathrm{P}\}$) has own hypotheses $H_0$ and $H_1$ and own full set of the allowed distributions $\mathrm{P} = H_0 \sqcup H_1$ (assumptions). But they have the same null distribution, so the p-value's value is the same for all of them (so we don't need to recalculate it if we want to change the perspective)! For practical real life task  we usually should choose only one most suitable perspective after careful analysis of our research goals, available information about the data generation process, etc. Our inferences are always highly dependent on a chosen perspective.

---

**Well, here are my questions:**

1. **Is my interpretation correct?**
2. **Where I can find a similar table for the one sample location tests?**
   It seems that the Wilcoxon signed-rank decision rule is a multiple perspective decision rule (MPDR) because [the wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test#One-sample_test) describes at least 3 different perspectives for it. But the wikipedia didn't say much about validity and consistency of the Wilcoxon signed-rank decision rule under these perspectives. Also I didn't find any sources describing properties of the one sample t-test under multiple perspectives.
3. Tests from the aforementioned table are usually called the two sample location tests (the two sample t-test, the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney test, the Brunner-Munzel test, etc.). Each of them has corresponding multiple perspective decision rule (MPDR) $\delta$, which can be applied under different perspectives. **Is the property of having MPDR typical only for location tests? What about other popular types of tests (variance tests, ANOVA, etc.), which of them typically have MPDR (if any)?**